# What is the difference between glBufferStorage and glBufferData?

Tags: opengl

> glBufferStorage creates a new immutable data store for the buffer
>   object currently bound to target​. The size of the data store is
>   specified by size​. If an initial data is available, its address may
>   be supplied in data​. Otherwise, to create an uninitialized data
>   store, data​ should be NULL​.

Immutable means that I can't mutate it right? But then "uninitialized data" would be pointless.

But it is not really immutable because we can specify `GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT​`

So what is the difference between glBufferStorage and glBufferData?

Comment: The buffer is immutable, the data can still be modified. OpenGL trusts that you won't tamper with the size or layout of the buffer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just so you know, this is the same principle behind `glTexStorage* (...)`. Effectively, you sign a contract with the API that says you will never be allowed to change certain properties of your object and in exchange this gives the object immutable status and allows you to do things you normally could not with it.

Texture Views are an interesting example, where the internal image data of an immutable texture can be shared between multiple texture objects and even have its format/dimensions reinterpreted (*e.g.* 1 slice of a 2D array texture can be shared and used as if it were an ordinary 2D texture).

For vertex buffers, immutable storage opens a class of performance optimizations (*e.g.* persistent mapped memory) that would not be possible if you could change the size of the buffer at any time. You create a buffer whose size can never be changed, but you are still free to send it new data at any time using `glBufferSubData* (...)` commands or by writing to the buffer while it is memory mapped.

With `glBufferData (...)`, you can call that command multiple times on the same object and it will orphan the old memory and allocate new storage. With `glBufferStorage (...)`, the buffer's size is set for the lifetime of the object (immutable) and it is an error (`GL_INVALID_OPERATION`) to call `glBufferStorage (...)` again once it has been allocated immutably.

In short, it is the *data store* (storage characteristics) that is immutable, not the actual data.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this words from [https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/buffer_storage.txt] show the key:

> OpenGL has long supported buffer objects as a means of storing data
>       that may be used to source vertex attributes, pixel data for textures,
>       uniforms and other elements. In un-extended GL, buffer data stores
>       are mutable - that is, they may be de-allocated or resized while they
>       are in use. The GL_ARB_texture_storage extension added immutable storage
>       for texture object (and was subsequently incorporated into OpenGL 4.2).
>       This extension further applies the concept of immutable storage to
>       buffer objects. If an implementation is aware of a buffer's immutability,
>       it may be able to make certain assumptions or apply particular
>       optimizations in order to increase performance or reliability.

These mentioned the mutable buffer maybe de-allocated or resized, and that comes from `glBufferData` which bring mutable buffer. But `glBufferStorage` will show you the ability to create immutable buffer.

The key here is 'immutable' means you can't resize or de-allocate it in the future, but not means you can't write/read data in it.

[Edit]
I think it's also good to append some sample, that can make the words from spec much more easy to understand, :)

- `glBufferData` sometime you may meet the words 'buffer orphan', normally you will see the similar calls like (there still some other way to do buffer orphan like `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT`, etc.):
  `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
   GLubyte* ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
   Foo(ptr, size);
   glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);`
- `glBufferStorage` don't allow you to de-allocate it [note the `0` parameter in `glBufferData`, but it keep the memory for the `Persistent-mapped Buffer`, normally you will see the usage looks like this:
  `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
   glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_MAP_PRESISTENT_BIT|GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT);
   GLubyte* ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, GL_MAP_PRESISTENT_BIT|GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT);
   Foo(ptr, size);`
  Note, the ptr just keeps on the same buffer's address, that means the buffer is persistented in the memory, and you don't need to unmap until you really don't need it

Thanks

Comment: You can use NULL for the data with glBufferStorage. You just cant resize it, so you have to set a fixed size. You can use, like you pointed out, the pointer to the mapped buffer to write to it, but data must not be set at glBufferStorage call.